# What's the difference between React Context API & Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, conceptual

As i understand it, they both deal with state. Hooks seem to be more internal to a components state, while the context api seems to solve the problem of prop drilling, creating a more global state? Is this false? What am I missing?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand, they have completely different use cases. Context allows you pass a value deep into the component tree, where the value could be any kind of prop, say, a color. By using context in this way, you avoid having to do `props.theme` on every component that needs a theme color passed to it.

Hooks, on the other hand, replace the need for classes; instead you create a function and `useState` enables you to pass in variables. I.e. Hooks allow you to take a React function component and add state to it, and apply lifecycle methods like componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate. This is useful because if you find your function requires state, you don't need to refactor it into a class, you can just add Hooks. :) Of course this choice is contentious among developers though.

Comment: Will not a custom hook allow you to use a value deep in component tree too? I.e. `const {value1, val2, method1, method2, ...} = useMyCustomHook()` in any component inside the component tree, and you get it all without any contexts and props.